# how can i return all the hyperlinks in a HTML file using LibXml 2.2 (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, libxml2, xpathquery

i want to return all the hyperlinks in a html. what would be the XPath Query that ?(Objective C)

Answer (score 0):

You can use next sample for your task

```
NSData *data = [inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
xmlDocPtr doc = xmlReadMemory([data bytes], [data length], "", NULL, XML_PARSE_RECOVER);

xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression(BAD_CAST("//a"), xpathCtx);

if (xpathObj && xpathObj->nodesetval) {
    for (int i = 0; i < xpathObj->nodesetval->nodeNr; ++i) {
        xmlNodePtr node = xpathObj->nodesetval->nodeTab[i];
        xmlChar *hrefProp = xmlGetProp(node, BAD_CAST("href");
        xmlChar *content = xmlNodeGetContent(node);

        NSString *hrefString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)hrefProp];
        NSString *contentString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)content];
        xmlFree(hrefProp);
        xmlFree(content);

        NSLog(@"Anchor %@, Content: %@", hrefString, contentString);
}
xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx);
xmlXPathFreeObject(xpathObj);
xmlFreeDoc(doc);
```

For setting up libxml2 read carefully section [Setting up your project file](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html).
Also you can download working sample from site and compile.

Comment: is this using libxml2.2 and objective c?

Comment: Also you can read the great article about using libxml2 in objective-c http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html

Comment: thank you so much. i visited that website, could u plz help me how should i send query for hyperlinks using those methods that ?

Comment: actually i am new into this topic, i dont know what lib to add to the headers and how to get the links in an Array, could you plz give me a complete sample? i will  be so thankful.

Comment: @SalehHosseinkhani stop asking people to do your work for you. Victor has given you a lot of help here, providing code and an additional resource for help on setting up libxml2. Instead of asking him to do your job, you should **learn** from this code so that you understand how it works. Or are you just going to get everyone else to write your app for you?